# Sample data - Streaming Analytics

Tags: iot, hana, streaming-analytics

I want to do small POC or project on HANA Streaming Analytics.

Can anyone please suggest me where I can get sample data to proceed or begin with?

Regards ,

Vinaya

Answer (score 0):

If any kind of data is fine, you can generate your own Sales Orders with transaction SEPM_DG.

On the *Basic Settings* tab:

- Mark *Recreate*
- Set *Sales Orders* to 20 million (or whatever you need)

[image: basic settings]

On the *Sales Orders* tab:

- Mark *Selected Date Interval*
- Set the dates, otherwise everything wil have today's date

Execute in the background.

Comment: this is fine.But Can u please tell me any other source ?